# HTML in WP7 without webbrowser control

Tags: html, windows-phone-7

Is there a control in WP7, other than a `WebBrowser`, which can display basic HTML (a few `<p>`s, `<b>`s, `<i>`s, `<div>`s and `<span>`s) inline?

I cannot use a `WebBrowser` for my app because I need the control to live inside a pivot (i.e. not swallow any gestures), and to keep the background of the rest of the pivot.

Comment: Could you just use IsHitTestVisible="False" ? That will prevent it gobbling gestures

Comment: The WebBrowser is no longer vertically scrollable either when this property is set.  This also doesn't solve the issue with the control obscuring the background of the rest of the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's basic markup you can always transform the HTML with the help of the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net) to a RichTextBox. (See: http://debugmode.net/2011/06/02/richtextbox-in-windows-phone-7-1-or-mango/)

Comment: Horrible solution really, but it looks like this is the only way. The HAP needs manual compiling for WP7.  And reformatting HTML in to a RichTextBox is laborious and error prone.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple to do with the WebBrowser control if you have a solid color background.  Basically you have the WebBroswer adjust the background color of the HTML content, and disable hit testing to stop the control from eating your gestures.

Some code examples can be found in this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/16/displaying-html-content-in-windows-phone-7.aspx

'Other' options for rendering HTML content in SL/WP7 tend to bite me in the rear in the long run.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't have a solid color background.